# Metadata API - listmetadata() for EmailTemplates is empty

Tags: email-template, metadata-api

I was able to retrieve metadata for DashboardFolders using [listMetadata()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_listmetadata.htm). However, the same does not apply for EmailTemplates where it returns empty. The inference from [this thread](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090NGIAY) is that it is not possible and can only be achieved from the query

```
SELECT DeveloperName FROM Folder WHERE Type = 'Email'
```

There should be a way since the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailtemplate.htm) explicitly states that this can be queried. Quoting the doc:

> You can’t use the wildcard (*) symbol with email templates in
>   package.xml.  To retrieve the list of email templates for populating
>   package.xml with explicit names, call listMetadata() and pass in
>   EmailTemplate as the type.

Are there any permissions that has to be set while retrieving the EmailTemplate folders? Additionally, there could be the default templates that are listed: SupportCaseAssignmentNotification, Support*, SalesNewCustomerEmail. There are around 13 of them. The above query does not include these. I can run a query on EmailTemplate:

```
SELECT DeveloperName, Body from EmailTemplate
```

How different is this from retrieving using Metadata API where SOAP API already satisfies by using one query whereas Metadata API could be invoked using list + retrieve calls (wrt EmailTemplates) ?

---

- UPDATE:

---

The solution is to:

1. List all the folders using @ashwani
2. Rerun listmetadata() by setting the folder names from step 1 and type = 'EmailTemplate'.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Exception:-

You need set Folder name instead of **Email Template** for Metadata as:

```
MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery queryEmailFolder= new MetadataService.ListMetadataQuery();
// Define Folder Name ''
queryEmailFolder.folder = '';
// Set EmailFolder
queryEmailFolder.type_x = 'EmailFolder';
queries.add(queryEmailFolder);       
MetadataService.FileProperties[] fileProperties = service.listMetadata(queries, 30);
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashwani. This returns metadata for folders when I query using package.xml with 'EmailTemplate' 'FolderLists'. How can I retrieve .email files using metadata API?

Comment: I've found the solution. List all the folders using your solution and then run another listmetadata() for each folder name with type 'EmailTemplate'.